# how to use pyparsing to match multiple lines while using iterator to read the file

Tags: python-2.7, pyparsing

In the definition of my Pyparsing grammar, there are some grammars which will match strings that span multiple lines. 
If I use the api like:

```
PyGrammar.parseString(open('file_name').read())
```

If will behave in the correct way.

However if I want to use the iterator to read the file like

```
with open('file_name') as f:
   for line in f:
      PyGrammar.parseString(line)
```

the parser will break

Is there a way to work around this case. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

According to Paul(the author of pyparsing)

```
with open('file_name') as f:
   for line in f:
      PyGrammar.parseString(line)
```

The code above is not the correct way to use pyparsing. Pyparsing needs to see all source texts before parsing the texts. So when I call parseString with each line of text, it does not work out. Another work around is to use a wrapper for it. like:

```
    # set up a generator to yield a line of text at a time
    linegenerator = open('big_hairy_file.txt')
    # buffer will accumulate lines until a fully parseable piece is found
    buffer = ""

    for line in linegenerator:
        buffer += line

        match = next(grammar.scanString(buffer), None)
        while match:
            tokens, start, end = match
            print tokens.asList()

            buffer = buffer[end:]
            match = next(grammar.scanString(buffer), None)
```